# Создание тригера MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

Здравствуйте,

Подскажите пожалуйста как создать тригер.
Мне требуется, чтобы при создании записи в таблице А создавалась запись в таблице Б  с полем id равным полю id из таблицы А являющемся Автоинкрементом(создаётся автоматом).

Версия MS sql 2000 sp4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TRIGGER [ti_B] ON [A]
FOR INSERT
AS
  INSERT INTO [B] ([id])
  SELECT    [ID]
  FROM  INSERTED
  RETURN
```

Касаемо получить последний ID - это не такой простой вопрос, как может показаться

Скорее всего стоит применить SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() после вставки в таблицу A. Эта функция работает только внутри сеанса и вернет ID последней строки вставленной в таблицу A.

Если речь о том, чтобы получить ID последней вставленной строки независимо от таблицы, то надо применить SELECT @@IDENTITY. Эта функция тоже работает внутри сеанса. Т.е. если вставляем строку в A, отрабатывает триггер на вставку. Если это триггер вставляет строку в какую-нибудь таблицу C, в которой есть какое-нибудь поле ID с автоинкерементом, то  SELECT @@IDENTITY вернет ID таблицы C

И третий случай. Если нужен ID не связанный с сеансом, то используйте SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('A')

Comment: Спасибо большое! 
Работает! 
Можешь ещё подсказать как в c# получить id последней добавленной строки?

Comment: допишу в ответ